# Правильное произношение "артель" или "артэль"?

Tags: фонетика

Недавно слышала современное исполнение песни "Дубинушка" (по голосу было на Расторгуева похоже). И там певец четко произносит: "Это песня рабочей артЭли". А как все-таки правильно произносить: мягко - Е или твердо - Э?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно мягко. Артель. (Орфоэпический словарь)